# Can I use competing in this reframed sentence?

Tags: grammar

I was reading a newspaper and then I came across this sentence:

> "The restaurant owner is competing more for guests than for the staff members."

So can I reframe it in this way

> "The restaurant owner is competing more for guests than competing for the staff members."

Comment: The omisson of a repeated verb (in this case "competing") is called _ellipsis._ It is common in English. You _could_ reframe it as you have done, but it is not idiomatic.

Comment: A better form of the original sentence might be "The restaurant owner is competing more for guests than for staff members".